# How to trigger a intent on response of another intent in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

```js
app.intent('Delivery', conv => {
  conv.ask("What a great day for Delivery!  We can provide more information on any of the categories shown below.");
  return axios.get(url).then((success) => {
    let items = {};
    for (let i of success.data.data) {
      let item = {};
      item.synonyms = [i.name];
      item.title = `${i.name}`;
      item.image = new Image({
        url: `${i.image}`,
        alt: 'Image alternate text',
      });
      item.description = `${i.description}`;
      items[i.id] = item;
    }
    conv.ask(new List({ title: 'Food Categories', items }));

  }).catch((error) => {
    conv.ask("Error in category");
  });
});
```

I have two intents in Dialogflow :

1. Delivery
2. Product

In the delivery intent, there are categories coming from API dynamically.

On the selection of a category, I'm just simply want to trigger the product intent, so that the user can select products from there.

How I can trigger that product intent on the selection of category.

Answer (score 0):

Your best options is to move the product intent logic to its own class or function. By doing this you make the code available for other intents and you won't have to copy and paste any code. So it makes your code more flexible and easier to read.

Whether you choose a function or class really is up to you. If you are just creating simple responses a function is enough, but if you find yourself importing/requiring the same classes over and over again, a class might be better.

Here is an example of a welcome intent class in NodeJS with Typescript:

```
/**
 * Welcome intent class
 */
export default class WelcomeIntent {
  invoke(conv: DialogflowConversation): DialogflowConversation {

    const greeting = this.getTimeOfDayGreeting();
    const response = "Welcome to my test app. How can I help?"

    const hasScreen = this.contextService.getContext(conv, "actions_capability_screen_output");

    if (hasScreen) {
      conv.ask(new Suggestions("What can I do?"));
    }

    conv.ask(greeting);
    return conv.ask(response);
  }

  private getTimeOfDayGreeting(): string {
    const currentHour = new Date().getHours();

    if (currentHour >= 6 && currentHour < 12) {
      return "Good morning.";
    } else if (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour < 18) {
      return "Good afternoon.";
    } else if (currentHour >= 18 && currentHour <= 23) {
      return "Good evening.";
    } else {
      return "Hello.";
    }
  }
}
```

Each time I want to welcome the user I just return `welcomeIntent.invoke()` and it welcomes the user.